# Drag and Drop File into Cursor Position Under Mouse

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, range, selection, ace-editor

Is there a way that you can do a file drag and drop operation into the DOM and detect the cursor position/range in the DOM where the mouse pointer is during the drop operation?

I can easily capture the Drop and get the file and content, but I can't seem to figure out how to drop custom HTML markup into the page at the drop location. The drop provides a mouse position, but the question is how to convert that (or anything else) into a cursor position and range into which I can paste a new link for the file (after I've saved it dynamically).

My use case is that I'm using Ace Editor (or any contentEditable area) and am trying to drag a file into the document at the location the mouse cursor is dropped. I then want to capture the file, and insert a link that references the capture file data which in this case is captured using the file API and stored on disk using a Web Browser control. I can get everything to works **except for detecting the drop location in my text document**.

So, any ideas how to acquire a selection range from a drop operation? I have the mouse coordinates, but I'm not sure how to correlate those to a text position from which a range can be created to insert my link into.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is a partial that addresses the Ace Editor portion of the question, but not how to do this using raw DOM operations. I'm hoping somebody else has a solution to doing this with raw DOM.

As to the Ace Editor solution, it has supporting APIs that allow mapping `PageX` and `PageY` positions to be mapped to physical row and column positions in the editor document using:

```
var pos = editor.renderer.screenToTextCoordinates(e.pageX, e.pageY)
```

Using that logic makes it possible to drop files at the drop position using the following code:

```
var $el = $("pre[lang]") // editor element
.on("dragover", function(e) {            
    $(this).addClass("hover");            
    return false;
})
.on("dragleave", function() {          
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
    return false;
})
.on("drop", function(e) {            
    e = e.originalEvent;
    e.preventDefault();            

    // grab the file
    var file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];

    // do something to save the file data to disk or server
    var imageUrl = "somelinktoimage";

    // Ace Editor logic
    var pos = editor.renderer.screenToTextCoordinates(e.pageX, e.pageY);                

    var sel = te.editor.getSelection();
    sel.selectToPosition(pos);
    var range = sel.getRange();
    range.setStart(pos.row,pos.column);
    range.setEnd(pos.row, pos.column);
    sel.setSelectionRange(range);
    te.editor.getSession().replace(range, "![" + file.name + "](" + imageUrl + ")");

    return false;
});
```